# how to Connect a C# project with database on the local network to edit and view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I have a Data Entry C# Project, 
I want to make it run on ***three computers*** on the same network and make their database on the network so everyone can see the edit of the others on the file i am using ***Access DB***.

I made the project already but the database are local with this connectionstring:-

```
    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

what i do now and how to setup it on three devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access database can be easily shared over the network or even online. [Ways to share an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74)

Can be accessed directly on db connection as:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\NETWORK-PC\SHAREDFOLDER\myAccessFile.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Comment: but this mean that i have to make for example the database on one of the three computers and take the name of the computer and the share folder and but them in my connection ? and if i do that if this device is off the program wont run right ??

Comment: YES. Absolutely YES :)

Comment: is there anyway to put this information dynamic into the connection because if i reinstalled the windows or any thing like that on any device of the three i have to change the code or if i made the pc name the same it will work ?

Comment: If you use datasource wizard to connect your application to your database, Microsoft by default save the application settings including the dataset connection automatically on "config" file of the application. It is located in your application directory as "APPNAME.EXE.CONFIG".
You can take a look at it. Any changes on your connection details, you can directly modify there using notepad or any text-based editors.

Comment: If you do hard-coding to connect to your database, you may use text files dabase to save your connection string(e.g. "ini" files, "cfg" files, "dll", etc.).
But take note that all this ways will expose your connection settings including your database password. You may choose to do some encryptions if you need to secure your database files.

Comment: changing the pc-name and sharing exactly same share folder location will also do the trick. But anyways, i assume you are not reinstalling windows everyday right? So you should not worry about this that much :'D

Comment: how to do encryption and what is the best use datasource wizard or hard coding ?

Comment: It depends upon the need. Hard-coding is the best if you want to keep your sensitive data and settings behind anything else. But if you're just starting on a specific thing, wizards will help you achieve what you want easily.

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457765/encryption-engine) this thread will help you start up on learning basic encryption on c# :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put database on some shared location of one machine and in DataSource of connection string you can provide that location. as Mentioned in first answer.
And you are Right that that machine is not available it won't work.